# Using labels on y axis of flot graph instead of numbers

Tags: javascript, graph, flot

At the moment each `team` is assigned a value e.g `team1.txt == 1`
So when i render the graph each team has a continuous line along the x-axis (timeline).
The y-axis has values `1 .. 3`, how could i change the y-axis' labels?
So that instead of seeing `1` as first metric on y-axis, I saw `team1.txt` .. then next value on y-axis would be `team2.txt`

html

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="demo-container">
        <div id="placeholder" class="demo-placeholder">
    </div>
</div>
<div id="chartLegend"></div>
</div>
```

javascript

```
text = '[{"name":"team1.txt","points":[[1389340501000,1],[1389370501000,1],[1389873602000,1],[1390046402000,1],[1390078402000,1]]},{"name":"team2.txt","points":[[1389370501000,2],[1389441601000,2],[1389528002000,2]]},{"name":"team3.txt","points":[[1389370501000,3],[1389441601000,3],[1389441601000,3]]}]';
var datasets = JSON.parse(text);

var data = [];
for (var i = 0; i < datasets.length; i++) {
    data.push({label: datasets[i].name, data: datasets[i].points});
}


$.plot($("#placeholder"), data, {
    xaxis: {
        mode: "time",
        min: (new Date(2014, 1, 1)).getTime(),
        max: (new Date()).getTime()
    },
    series: {
        stack: true,
        lines: {
            show: true
        },
        points: {
            show: true
        }
    },
    grid: {
        hoverable: true,
        clickable: true
    },
    legend: {
        noColumns: 5,
        container: $("#chartLegend")
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `tickFormatter` function for that:

```
yaxis: {
    tickFormatter: function (val, axis) {
        if (datasets[val - 1])
            return datasets[val - 1].name;
        else
            return '';
    }
},
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J7nB6/1/) for a working demo.

PS: I had to change the `xaxis min` value to `new Date(2014, 0, 1)` (January is month 0, see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)).

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
yaxis:{mode: "categories", tickLength:0}
```

That works for me, adds all different strings values i have automatically(when they are sendt in as y point). here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Margo/yKG7X/4/

remmenber to add this script: http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/jquery.flot.categories.js

You could also use something like:

```
yaxis: { ticks: [[0, 'true'], [1, 'false']] }
```

.. if your values are predefined.

Hope it helps :)